Cannot connect to Mac from Visual Studio 2022 after 17.11.4 update
After the latest visual studio update the connection to Mac doesnt seem to work. I have deleted the MonoTouch folder, removed & re added the Mac, restarted both windows & the Mac to no avail. The link icon for the selected Mac is not shown after the connection attempt finishes and I get the below message.

Disconnected
The Connection to 'My Mac Name' has been finished.

Mac OS : Sequoia 15.0 &
Xcode  : 16.0
Update 1
Upgraded to Sequoia 15.0 now & also deleted the XMA folders on Mac and Windows before attempting again but still the same issue.
Update 2
I tried to rollback to the previous version but this didn't help either as I get a version mismatch since I have now updated Xcode & MacOS to the latest. I had to update VS2022 to 17.11.4 again.
Update 3
The Pair to Mac window quickly goes through various status messages & I managed to spot the error which is below.

Error The connection cannot continue because the remote iOS SDK was not found or is corrupted.
If the issue persists, please try removing the
'~/Library/Caches/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/' folder on the MAC and try    again

I tried deleting the XMA folder on both MAC & Windows but this doesnt seem to help either.
One of the old threads mentions adding a space or making a change in the Csproj would help so I tried that too. Also tried creating a brand new MAUI project and connecting with it. None of these help

What's your MacOS version and Xcode version?

I installed .NET SDK 8.0 on both Mac and Windows & the connection succeeds now. It probably was an issue with the SDK's and installing it solved the problem.
I do get a warning that Xcode (16.0) is not compatible with version 17.11.4 of Visual Studio 2022 & Xcode 15.4 is needed hence no simulators are being shown.
UPDATE 1
This is a known issue and further details & workarounds can be found here
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/20802
UPDATE 2
I had to download an earlier Xcode beta 16 compatible with the latest VS. I pointed the command line tools in Xcode Settings > Locations to the Beta version found in the drop down and downloaded a version of the beta Simulator iOS 17.5 which works now

The issue occurred because Xamarin service was offline, now the server is back online, paired Mac is now available. You can check the issue in software.xamarin.com required for .net maui to ios is offline again
Also, if you have set "DisableMonoValidation" = 'True' in the registry, please remove it, it was just masking the issue before and may cause unwanted issues in the future.
If you're using Xcode16 according to Xcode 16.0 Support for .NET 8/9 and MAUI, the current stable version of the workload is not compatible with Xcode 16, and the Xcode 16-compatible .NET9 Preview is expected to be released as early as November

This key already exists in my registry, I was getting the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error so I had to add this in and it fixed that. The current problem still persists though

I updated my answer, you can check it.
